# How to display appendix letter in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

Assuming the following code:

```
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
....

\begin{appendices}
\appendix

\chapter{Foo}
\label{app:foo}
text1

\chapter{Bar}
\label{app:bar}
text2

\end{appendices}
```

The table of contents shows:

```
Appendices
Foo
Bar
```

However, the appendices headers themselves are in the form of `A. Foo` and `B. Bar`.

How can I force the table of contents to display the letters as well, i.e. the following table of contents if required:

```
Appendices
A. Foo
B. Bar
```

**EDIT 1:**

Any other working solution (regardless used package) that works with pdflatex is sufficient :)

Comment: What is the advantage of using the package `appendix`?

Comment: If I use the non-mwe above I don't get `A. Foo` and the letters do **appear** in the ToC

Comment: I've no idea, I just found similar example on sharelatex tutorial page. I'd be grateful if you provide some alternative working example :) thank you

Comment: @ChristianHupfer really? That's really weird since I obtain a different result

Comment: @petrbel: Just as 'proof' see my 'answer' below

Comment: in addition to what @Sigur said, don't use the command`\appendix` and the environment `appendices`

Comment: @touhami what should I use instead? And why is `\appendix` incorrect? What are the drawbacks?

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that the package is not required (obligation) you can use just `\appendix` to start your appendix. if you prefer use the package then use the environment or the command `\appendix`but not both.

Comment: @touhami all right then, I understand - thanks for a tip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\begin{appendices}
\appendix

\chapter{Foo}
\label{app:foo}
text1

\chapter{Bar}
\label{app:bar}
text2

\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are right, I misled you - ToC is correct, however, navigation in the left panel of the pdf viewer does not show the letter. It's probably viewer-related problem. Thanks

Comment: @petrbel -- you might want to add the information to your question that the "toc" you are referring to is the pdf bookmarks list.

Comment: see my comment above

Comment: I will change my answer later on